# Responsive mega-dropdown for products

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have trouble creating a mega-dropdown menu for Products. I want to create a responsive (I use Bootstrap) dropdown which drops down from the entire nav like most big companies.
Here is how it looks like:

[image: navigation]

I want the dropdown to be from NAME to CONTACT. I will populate it with divs with pictures and text. How can I do that? 
Advice, directions or explanation would be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Here is the navigation in the HTML file:

```
<nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"
                   data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top">INVACU</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#about">About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#services">Services</a>
                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">Products <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">VSU 200</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a class="page-scroll" href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Here is the navigation in the CSS file:

```
.navbar-default {
    border-color: rgba(34,34,34,.05);
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    background-color: #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .35s;
    -moz-transition: all .35s;
    transition: all .35s;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: 'Open Sans','Helvetica Neue',Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #f05f40;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
    color: #eb3812;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #222;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
    color: #f05f40;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus {
    color: #f05f40!important;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.navbar-default .nav > li.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav>li.active>a:focus:hover {
    background-color: transparent;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
        background-color: transparent;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
    }

    .navbar-default .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix {
        border-color: rgba(34,34,34,.05);
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #f05f40;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .navbar-header .navbar-brand:focus {
        color: #eb3812;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus {
        color: #222;
    }

    .navbar-default.affix .nav > li>a:hover,
    .navbar-default.affix .nav>li>a:focus:hover {
        color: #f05f40;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your code first, ask later

Comment: @Justinas I had some trouble posting it directly on stackoverflow for some reason. I updated my question with pastebin links.

Comment: @Codearts Put the code inside code blocks and you won't have display problems on here.

Comment: @J.Titus I did. Half of my code was displayed as normal text for some reason. Nevermind.

Comment: @J.Titus My fault. I did the whole thing wrong. I fixed it.